# c# convert image formats to jpg

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

I need to get a picture from the user, with different format extensions, and I want to always save it as "jpg", for easy handling.
is there a good way do that in c# without arming the quality?

Comment: It depends on platform - web, application, mobile or even if yout take photo card :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.encoderparameter.aspx

```
private void VaryQualityLevel()
{
// Get a bitmap.
Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(@"c:\TestPhoto.jpg");
ImageCodecInfo jpgEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);

// Create an Encoder object based on the GUID
// for the Quality parameter category.
System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder myEncoder =
    System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;

// Create an EncoderParameters object.
// An EncoderParameters object has an array of EncoderParameter
// objects. In this case, there is only one
// EncoderParameter object in the array.
EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 
    50L);
myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
bmp1.Save(@"c:\TestPhotoQualityFifty.jpg", jpgEncoder, 
    myEncoderParameters);

myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 100L);
myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
bmp1.Save(@"c:\TestPhotoQualityHundred.jpg", jpgEncoder, 
    myEncoderParameters);

// Save the bitmap as a JPG file with zero quality level compression.
myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 0L);
myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
bmp1.Save(@"c:\TestPhotoQualityZero.jpg", jpgEncoder, 
    myEncoderParameters);

}

...

private ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
{

    ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();

    foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
    {
        if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
        {
            return codec;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Above code doesnt seem to work for me.It is unable to find ImageCodecInfo class,

Comment: it works.. btw Whats does @symbol in @c:\TestPhotoQualityZero.jpg signify

Comment: @SudarshanTaparia It signifies that every character in the string after that symbol should be treated as is. You need to use double backslash ("\\") otherwise, as backslash with some symbol mean a "special character". Like "\n" is a "new line" and is converted into character with code 13.

Answer (score 18):

I use this simple extension to convert a stream, all it does is convert it though and does nothing for quality.

```
public static Stream ConvertImage(this Stream originalStream, ImageFormat format)
{
                var image = Image.FromStream(originalStream);

                var stream = new MemoryStream();
                image.Save(stream, format);
                stream.Position = 0;
                return stream;
}
```

usage:

```
var outputStream = gifStream.ConvertImage(ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: this is the easiest solution for this problem. most of the developers just omit it :3

Comment: This solution didn't work for svg images, am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, vector graphics work differently than rasterized images.

Answer (score 2):

> Windows GDI+ provides the [Image class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7e7b2kd) and the [Bitmap class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) for storing
>   images in memory and manipulating images in memory. GDI+ writes images
>   to disk files with the help of image encoders and loads images from
>   disk files with the help of image decoders.

Check [Image.Save Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ex6sdew) overloads to implement your functionality. which support various image format of type [ImageFormat Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat).

follow example on [Image.Save Method (String, ImageCodecInfo, EncoderParameters)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ytz20d80), which will let you save `Jpg` file with encoding etc.

code snippet:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
class Example_SetJPEGQuality
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Bitmap myBitmap;
        ImageCodecInfo myImageCodecInfo;
        Encoder myEncoder;
        EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter;
        EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters;

        // Create a Bitmap object based on a BMP file.
        myBitmap = new Bitmap("Shapes.bmp");

        // Get an ImageCodecInfo object that represents the JPEG codec.
        myImageCodecInfo = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");

        // Create an Encoder object based on the GUID

        // for the Quality parameter category.
        myEncoder = Encoder.Quality;

        // Create an EncoderParameters object.

        // An EncoderParameters object has an array of EncoderParameter

        // objects. In this case, there is only one

        // EncoderParameter object in the array.
        myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

        // Save the bitmap as a JPEG file with quality level 25.
        myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 25L);
        myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
        myBitmap.Save("Shapes025.jpg", myImageCodecInfo, myEncoderParameters);

        // Save the bitmap as a JPEG file with quality level 50.
        myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 50L);
        myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
        myBitmap.Save("Shapes050.jpg", myImageCodecInfo, myEncoderParameters);

        // Save the bitmap as a JPEG file with quality level 75.
        myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 75L);
        myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
        myBitmap.Save("Shapes075.jpg", myImageCodecInfo, myEncoderParameters);
    }
```

// Codec info

```
  private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(String mimeType)
        {
            int j;
            ImageCodecInfo[] encoders;
            encoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
            for(j = 0; j < encoders.Length; ++j)
            {
                if(encoders[j].MimeType == mimeType)
                    return encoders[j];
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Hope this help..

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
       public static class BitmapExtension
       {
          public static void Save(this Bitmap bitmap, String fileName, ImageFormat imageFormat, long quality = 75L)
          {
             using (var encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1))
             using (encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, quality))
             {
                ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();

                bitmap.Save(fileName, codecs.Single(codec => codec.FormatID == imageFormat.Guid), encoderParameters);
             }
          }
       }

       ...

       Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap("myImage.bmp");

       bitmap.Save("myImage.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg, 50L);
```