# Converting an image (as IFormFile or MemoryStream) to JPEG

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, jpeg

```
        // validate file as image (acceptable formats: jpeg, png, gif, bmp)
        string FileValidity = FileValidation.VerifyInputFile(imageFile);
        if (FileValidity != "ok")
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Invalid file uploaded: " + FileValidity);
            return BadRequest(FileValidity);
        }

        // preprocess and serialize image
        using var imageMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        imageFile.CopyTo(imageMemoryStream);
        string serializedImage = ImagePreprocessing.Preprocess(imageMemoryStream);
        _logger.LogInformation("Image has been serialized");
```

Hello,
So in my code the user uploads an image, where acceptable formats are jpeg, png, gif and bmp.
The file is being validated first (as for whether it is indeed any of these formats) - see `FileValidation` class.

If it is indeed an image, it'll then go through the `ImagePreprocessing` class, where it'll be resized and cropped, and then serialized as base64.

For uniformity, I wish that every input of the `ImagePreprocessing.Preprocess` method will be an image of jpeg format.
Therefore, I'm looking for a way to convert the image to jpeg.
How can it be done? I've been trying to use ImageFormat but it didn't work quite well.
I need the conversion to jpeg to take place so that the `imageMemoryStream` that is fed into the `Preprocess` method will already contain the jpeg representation of the image - meaning that whatever format the original image was (jpeg/png/gif...) - they will all be represented as jpeg before being processed.

Thanks.

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/17922473/9641914

Comment: tried it, it doesn't help :( i cant use ImageFormat, probably because im using .net 5.0

Comment: To use that solution, you should install `System.Drawing.Common` package. But it is Windows-only, so you won't be able to run your application on Linux. Is it ok in your case?